open3d non blocking window manager
I would to make a class that holds a history of objects (in my case graphs) each graph can get a list of (label, geometry) tuples from the get_geometries method I would like to always display the most recent graph as well as have the display be interactive (look around with the mouse)
What I have right now is the following
class Graph_Manager:
def __init__(self):
    self.graph_history = []
    self.last_displayed_labels = []

    self.app = o3d.visualization.gui.Application.instance
    self.app.initialize()

    self.vis = o3d.visualization.O3DVisualizer(title="Scene Graph Visualizer", width=1000, height=1000)
    self.app.add_window(self.vis)

    self.app.run_in_thread(self.update_display)

def update_display(self):
    while True:
        print(f"update display looped")
        if len(self.graph_history) == 0:
            geo = get_geometries(None)  # Get geometries for the initial graph
        else:
            geo = get_geometries(self.graph_history[-1])  # Get geometries for the latest graph
        
        #print(f"{geo=}")

        # Clear previous geometry and add new geometries to the visualizer
        #print(f"{dir(self.vis)=}")
        for old_geometry in self.last_displayed_labels:
            #print(f"removing {old_geometry}")
            self.vis.remove_geometry(old_geometry)

        self.last_displayed_labels = []
        for label, geometry in geo:
            self.vis.add_geometry(label, geometry)
            self.last_displayed_labels.append(label)

        self.vis.post_redraw()
        #self.app.post_to_main_thread(self.vis, self.vis.post_redraw)
        #self.app.run_one_tick()
        self.app.post_to_main_thread(self.vis, self.app.run_one_tick)
        
        time.sleep(0.05)

def add_graph(self, graph):
    self.graph_history.append(graph)

This currently just shows a black screen, I believe because of the main thread requirements, Any help is appreciated.
O3DVisualizer
Application
